# Help! Need a different logo on my main page from my other pages

Tags: functions, customization, logo

First off I am not a coder and its my first time creating a website and using word press.  I am having an issue with my Logo.  It is very large and only would like to use this logo and size on my main page.  All the other pages I would like to just use a very small logo.  Please help!  Like I said I am very new to this so I need very basic instructions.  Your help would be so appreciated - I am a new business and cant afford to hire a developer at this time.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your header.php which you copied into your child theme, replace the logo request with this:

```
If (is_front() || is_home) {
//Your logo for the front page
}Else {
// Your other logo
}
```

If your home page is static use is_front.  If your home page is blogs use is_home.

I looked up your theme "classify".  If it's the one from themeforest login to your themeforest and download the complete theme folder not just the WordPress install file.  In the file you downloaded you'll find the "classify-child.zip" install that as well into your WordPress theme.  this will make a copy of the theme that you can customize but won't be affected when you update the actual classify WordPress theme next time.

Now, from the classify folder, copy the header.php file into the classify-child folder in your wordpress install.  Make the changes in the new header.php file that is in your classify-child theme.

Comment: Ok so like I said I am a beginner.  I have one theme. Classify.  I found the theme editor and than I found header.php.  Is this where I should be going?

Comment: Amanda, that could work.  I added a bit more information into the answer above.  If you don't know how to get the child theme setup you can do a bit more research or if you plan on NEVER updating the theme you can make the changes right in that header.php file you found.  I strongly suggest child theme though.